# call function only once after double click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this div box which calls a function "nextStep" onclick.

```js
function nextStep() {
  console.log("NEXT");
}
```

```html
<div onclick="nextStep()">test</div>
```

Problem is, if I double click the div box the function will call twice.
That should not be possible.

How can I disallow this?

Comment: please clarify:  Should the button only ever be clickable *once* or should it be re-enabled at some specific time in the future after clicking once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time to lock your double click.

Run snippet. If the previous click was less than 0.3 seconds ago, the click will be blocked. You can adjust the amount of time as needed.

```js
function nextStep() {
  var $div = $(".test");
  if (!$div.data('lockclick') || +new Date() - $div.data('lockclick') > 300) {
    console.log("NEXT");
  }
  $div.data('lockclick', +new Date());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" onclick="nextStep()">Test</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you can use jquery's [`.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) method to only allow it to be clicked once.

```js
$("#mydiv").one("click", nextStep);

function nextStep() {
    console.log("NEXT")
}
```

```css
#mydiv { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">click me</div>
```

Other alternatives including adding a class with [`pointer-events:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: He just wants to prevent double click. The listener should work more than only one time...

Comment: @biberman then why does OP state, clearly, "*call function only once*"? And also "*That [call twice] should not be possible*" Your assertion that "The listener should work more than only one time" is not stated in the question and you've **assumed** that requirement.  There's no mention of being able to click it again later.

Comment: @freedomn-m, Most likely, the OP is no longer interested in this question.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov agreed - I wish there was a close vote for "OP has been unresponsive" :)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the triggering on double click you can save the "clicked" status in a variable and ask for it before executing the function code.

If you want to use the `onclick` listener again (with single click) you can reset the variable after a short time (300ms should be enough for preventing the double click).

```js
let clicked = false;

function nextStep() {
  if (!clicked) {
    clicked = true;
    console.log("NEXT");
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    clicked = false;
  }, 300);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="nextStep()">test</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the event listener 'dblclick' in native javascript

```js
const myDiv= document.querySelector('#my-div');

myDiv.addEventListener('dblclick', function (e) {
  console.log('in double click')
});
```

```css
#my-div{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='my-div'>test</div>
```

Comment: He wants to prevent the triggering on double click and not detect the double click...,

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to do it in FP style

```js
const once = f => {
  let called = false;
  return () => {
    if (called) return;
    called = true
    f();
  }
}

function nextStep() {
  console.log("NEXT");
}

const nextStepOnce = once(nextStep)
```

```html
<div onclick="nextStepOnce()">test</div>
```